# Continuous deployment from a test server to a production server, using git

Tags: git, merge

I've a branch `origin/master` (from a test server) that is ahead of a branch `master` by N commits (on a production server) . I want to apply the commit from  `origin/master` to `master` one by one, in order to observe, at each step, how the application react to these commits.

I've used `git cherry-pick` but then the commit checksum is modified. I would like to keep the same history.

I can also look at the list of commits from `origin/master` and run `git merge <commit>`, one by one, manually choosing the right commit, but I'm looking for a command saying something such as "Apply the first commit that is different between the two branches".

Comment: you could cherry-pick, reset and merge, but it's a bit cumbersome. Perhaps this process could be automated using some shell script

Answer (score 1):

What about this (not tested) bash script?

```
# CREATES A master_test BRANCH STARTING ON master
git checkout -b master_test master

# FOR ALL DIFFERENT COMMITS
for h in $(git log --pretty=format:%H master..origin/master)
do
    # MERGE THE COMMIT
    git merge $h

    # PAUSE TO "OBSERVE"
    echo "Paused"
    read pause
done
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the for loop takes all commits in one iteration because of some bash obscure behavior. Probably related to the processing of newlines coming from the git log command.

Comment: Check the value of your IFS variable (echo X${IFS}X). I think you have a non-default value for the IFS variable. The default value is whitespace (space, tab, and newline), but it may be changed, for example, to parse a comma-separated data file (More info: search for "IFS" in this document: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

Comment: Using `IFS=$' \t\n'` doesn't solve the problem, I'm using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) for this. It automates the process (using a binary search) of picking commits between known good and bad commits to find the original commit that caused the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: But indeed, I would like to apply each commit, one by one, from the first commit different between two branches. How to use `bisect` to do this?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni It won't apply them one at a time, but do a binary search between two commits to find the problem. If you are looking for a problematic commit, a binary search should be faster than applying each commit one at a time. If you do want to see what your code does after each commit, then bisect won't help you.

Comment: It's for continuous deployment from a test server to a production server. So `git bisect` is not the solution even if it's an interesting tool.

Answer (score 0):

The checksum is a hash computed using the committer, commit date, author, commit message, and hash of tree objects as well as other info.  It will be unique any time the commit is modified and I don't know of any way around it (or if it would even be something that you would want).

It sounds like you're looking for the `-x` parameter which will append the original commit hash automatically to the commit message when you cherry-pick.

Here's an example I just made:

```
git cherry-pick -x 60aa086c5d8d68fdeb47d02d9e06a6420e721295
```

and the history

```
    git log
    commit 6287d63090736c9a1ae58d578d2d395896561f27
    Author: Kief Kraken <kief@gitkraken.com>
    Date:   Tue Sep 13 16:31:36 2016 -0700

        original commit message 
       (cherry picked from commit 60aa086c5d8d68fdeb47d02d9e06a6420e721295)
```

This way you always have the original commit hash so you can find the original commit if you would ever need.

Comment: Using `git merge <commit>`, selecting manually the right commit does the trick. But I would like to automatically select the first commit that is different between the two branches.